# Dynamic http inbound gateway using spring-integration-dsl

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I am trying to create and register runtime Integration flow for HTTP inbound gateway using Java DSL as code provided below

```
@Autowired
private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RestClientDemoApplication.class, args);
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="httpRequest")
public String upCase(String in) {
    System.out.println("message received" + in);
    return in.toUpperCase();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel directChannel(){
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

/*@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inbound() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
            .requestPayloadType(String.class).replyChannel(directChannel()))
        .channel("httpRequest")
        .get();
}
*/


@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
     IntegrationFlow flow;
     IntegrationFlowRegistration theFlow;
    flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
                .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
                .requestPayloadType(String.class).replyChannel(directChannel()))
            .channel("httpRequest")
            .get();

      theFlow = this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
}
```

In this case my request url ("/foo") is not mapping with the server as when I send the message from the HTTP client then no message is received on server side.
but when I uncomment the above bean (inbound) i.e **creating a Bean for Integration flow**  and comment the flow creation and register code(**remove runtime integration flow code**) in run method 
as below it **work fine**:

```
@Autowired
private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(RestClientDemoApplication.class, args);
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="httpRequest")
public String upCase(String in) {
    System.out.println("message received" + in);
    return in.toUpperCase();
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel directChannel(){
    return MessageChannels.direct().get();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow inbound() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
            .requestPayloadType(String.class).replyChannel(directChannel()))
        .channel("httpRequest")
        .get();
}



@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {


     /*IntegrationFlow flow;
     IntegrationFlowRegistration theFlow;

     flow = IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/foo")
                .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
                .requestPayloadType(String.class).replyChannel(directChannel()))
            .channel("httpRequest")
            .get();

      theFlow = this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();*/ 
}
```

My HTTP outbound gateway Code is as follow

```
    flow = IntegrationFlows.from(directChannel()).handle(Http.outboundGateway("https://localhost:8448/foo")
            .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST).expectedResponseType(String.class)).channel("httpReply").get();

    theFlow = this.flowContext.registration(flow).register();
```

Please help me with the above issue or provide a solution to create Http inbound gateway at runtime if this approach is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4436.

Unfortunately there is no simple workaround for your to go ahead, unless you could expose just only one REST endpoint and do routing inside the `IntegrationFlow` according the accepted HTTP request.